# My joint end-nodes do not respect my stroke styles

Tags: inkscape, path, vector

[image: just a sample path]

I make many Bezier paths when I trace a photo. Often I join both end-nodes with the "join selected nodes". In my illustration the top left node is such a combination of two former end-nodes.

You can see that all other nodes are respecting my stroke style, where I have opted for "round" joining and "round" caps.

I have tried selecting the problem-node and work through all the options, but cannot find a command to apply my stroke style to this node. Please just let me know where to go.

I would normally expect, such a freshly created node to apply the stroke style which (I believe) is attached to an entire path. I have never seen cases where stroke styles or fill styles only apply to portions of a path. But I do not insist on automatic, I am willing to "edit" my last made nodes to make them show my stroke style. But how?

I am using Inkscape 0.92.0 r15299

Update: Installed Inkscape 0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06) and still cannot fix my existing paths. But any paths I am creating now, have got proper nodes, which ARE respecting the path stroke style.

Update: After input from @Billy I shut down all my instances of Inkscape and reopened my work in progress. Surprise: Any new paths I am now creating with the Bezier tool, are making all nodes correct, even the end-nodes, according to my stroke style. But the ones I had created earlier today still refuse to have ALL their nodes comply. Feels like a bug now, unless somebody can explain what is happening or how I can edit nodes for styles.

Update: Even with the latest version of Inkscape I did more work and found a few corner-nodes which behave zombie like: When I drag them around, they randomly jump between a "round join" (as requested per Stroke style) and a "miter join" (the pointy one, in violence of what Stroke style demands). This happens somehow based on the angle of the two adjoining segments. It looks random, but I will investigate this behaviour further and maybe manage to make screenshots. Need to catch a deadline, sorry.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - [see screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/2fdMc) - perhaps you could share the SVG on filedropper(dot)com and post the link here.

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr that is encouraging. I just edited and stated my Inkscape version. Will try to shut down Inkscape (and Windows in next step) and see whether it had just gotten zombied.

Comment: There's been a recent Inkscape update to 0.92.2.  I was using 0.92.1 r15371.  Could have been a bug, or just a glitch. Who knows!

Comment: Check to see if you have multiple points on top of eachother?

Comment: No, I do not have multiple points. My paths are simple, often just boxes. I join both end-nodes, which makes precisely one node; no doubt. I have even observed a very few random wrong nodes in the middle of a path today - which is also confirming the bug-theory.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed the very lastest version as advised by @BillyKerr, thanks. I have updated my question: From now on, new Bezier paths which I make, have all good nodes. But I still cannot fix existing nodes. My best workaround is so far to add an extra node next to a bad one. Then delete the bad node and move the fresh node over. But that is a lot of work, almost tracing my photos again. So still hoping for some idea how to "edit" existing bad nodes.

Comment: Can you check there are no path effects or filters on your path - just on the off-chance that there's something like that causing it.  It's the only thing I can think of that might mess it up.

Comment: You don't need a filedropper. Just mark the path, open the svg-viewer in inkscape, give the path a speaking name, i.e. pathologogic instead of path42314 and save the file. Now grep for the xml with  *grep -a3 pathologic sample.svg* RESULT:  <path
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       id="pathologic"
       d="M 151,1473 300.3,1775 551,1521 779.3,1736 665.9,1467 552.7,1715 Z"
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:21.2598;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" />

Comment: Now copy the code to your question and format it as code. We then can read the source and try it out ourselves.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was abroad for a week and we helped with a medical emergency too and today was all day on and off power cuts. This question is still open and I will get to it when the crazyness calms down. Sorry for beeing late.